# Outlook COM Addin bundle install with a seperate msi file C#

Tags: c#, outlook, windows-installer, outlook-addin, comaddin

I'm trying to be able to bundle an Outlook addin (.dll file) that I've made in C# with a separate msi installer (not the default one created in Visual Studio).  The add-in works great using the default setup that Visual Studio creates but I'm looking to install the .dll file using a different msi as to bundle it with another piece of software and I'm not sure what registry values or other details need to be worked out that will allow Outlook for recognize the addin.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this tutorial.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ff937654.aspx